# How to set data using optional java

Tags: java, collections, stream, option-type, lombok

I am new to Optional and functional programming.
How do I optimize the below code using optional(line: 4 to line: 7)?

```
@Getter @Setter
class Score{
    Double score;
    Double percentage;
}

Optional<Score> scoreOptional getScore(){}
```

How to set score and percentage data using optional

```
public Optional<Score> calculate(){
  Optional<Score> scoreOptional = getScore();
 
  // I am setting data like this
  if(scoreOptional.isEmpty())
     return scoreOptional;

   //line : 4
   Score score= scoreOptional.get();
   score.setScore(13D);
   score.setPercentage(15D);
   return Optional.of(score);
   //line: 7

}
```

Comment: Line 7 may be `return scoreOptional;`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ifPresent`, this might make the code look more clean. However I am not sure if this would "optimize" the performance.

```java
public Optional<Score> calculate(){
    Optional<Score> scoreOptional = getScore();
    scoreOptional.ifPresent(score -> {
        score.setScore(13d);
        score.setPercentage(15d);
    });
    
    return scoreOptional;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Optional.map()`:

```
public Optional<Score> calculate() {
    return getScore().map(score -> {
        score.setScore(13D);
        score.setPercentage(15D);
        return score;
    });
}
```